# AJAX stored requests and form submitting

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, validation

I am working on a jQuery validation "plugin" (not yet a plugin) that use my Zend_Form validators to verify the fields before submitting, client-side, **so I only have to specify my constraints one time instead of two** (Zend Validators + jQuery Validate Plugin, for example).

I store the validation AJAX requests for each field, then wait for them to finish, and then read the results and show or not an error message.

The problem : when I enter validated strings and hit submit, it shows no errors (good so far), but I have to **re-click the submit button** the form to really submit it.

Making a `return true` or `false` inside the `.whenAll` function is ignored and does not work, that's why I used a flag to tell the function if yes or no it can really submit the form.

```
$(function() {

    var form = $('form'); // target form
    var requests = [], validations = []; // used to store async requests and their results
    var nbInputs = $('input[type="text"], input[type="password"]').length; // number of inputs we want to check in the form
    var cancelSubmit = true; // skip validation flag

    form.submit(function( ) {

        // if we call the submit inside the function, skip validation and do submit the form
        if(cancelSubmit === false) {
            console.log('[-] cancelSubmit is false. Validation skipped.');
            this.submit();
            return true;
        }

        console.log('[-] Entering validation');

        // resetting requests and validations
        requests.length = 0;
        validations.length = 0;

        // for each input (text/password), storing the validation request
        $('input[type="text"], input[type="password"]').each(function(i) {

            var validatorField = $(this).attr('data-validator');
            var valueField = $(this).val();

            postData = {
                validator: validatorField,
                value: valueField
            };

            // storing requests into an array
            requests.push($.post('/validate', postData));
        });

        (function($) {
            $.whenAll = function() {
                return $.when.apply($, arguments);
            };
        })(jQuery);

        // when all the requests are done and returned a response
        $.whenAll(requests).then(function() {

            // show the validation status for each input
            $.each(requests, function(i, element) {
                element.done(function(data) {

                    // response is formatted like this
                    // { valid: 1 } or { valid: 0, message:"This is the error message" }
                    json = $.parseJSON(data);
                    formGroup = $('input:eq('+i+')').parent();

                    // if it isn't valid, show error and store result
                    if(json.valid == 0) {
                        if($('span.help-block', formGroup).length == 0) {
                            $(formGroup).addClass('has-error').append('<span class="help-block">'+json.message+'</span>');
                            $('label', formGroup).addClass('control-label');
                        }

                        validations.push(0);
                    }
                    // else, remove error (if there was) and store the result
                    else if(json.valid == 1) {

                        if($(formGroup).hasClass('has-error'))
                        {
                            $(formGroup).removeClass('has-error');
                            $('.help-block', formGroup).remove();
                        }

                        validations.push(1);
                    }

                    // if we got all the validations required
                    if(validations.length == nbInputs)
                    {
                        console.log('[-] All validations have been done.');

                        // and if no error ("0") in the results, we resubmit the form with skip-flag
                        if($.inArray(0, validations) == -1){
                            console.log('[-] No errors. Submitting form.');
                            cancelSubmit = false;
                            form.off('submit');
                            form.submit();
                        }
                        else
                            console.log('[-] There is still errors.');
                    }
                });
            });
        });

        // there are errors, so we won't submit the form
        if(cancelSubmit === true)
            return false;
    });
});
```

Do you see a logic flaw in my code ? Maybe re-submitting the form with a flag isn't the right way to do it ?

Comment: Yes, you're returning from a sub scope rather than from the form submit handler Instead, always prevent the submit, and then force it to submit with `form[0].submit()` when you want it to submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're returning from a sub scope rather than from the form submit handler. Instead, always prevent the submit, and then force it to submit with `form[0].submit()` when you want it to submit.

```
form.submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ...

    // now i want to submit...
    form[0].submit();
```

`form[0].submit()` will bypass your jquery bound submit handler.

Comment: Thank you Kevin. I got this error : `Uncaught TypeError: Property 'submit' of object #<HTMLFormElement> is not a function`. I deleted the `.off('submit')`, same error.

Comment: Solved : it was a conflict with my button which was `id="submit"`. I just renamed it.